# error in ddply function sum?

Tags: r, plyr

first time posting here! I am having a problem using the ddply function. I have this table that I would like to summarize using the column "LC", and adding the values in the column "Area":

```
  ID LC  per     Area
1  1  7 0.29  62428.3
2  1  7 0.79 170063.3
3  1  4 0.40  86108.0
4  1  7 0.43  92566.1
5  1  6 1.00 215270.0
6  1  7 0.61 131314.7
```

Based on this dataframe I would expect exactly this:

```
LC   Area
4  86108.0
6 215270.0
7 456372.4
```

Applying the ddply function I get these results:

```
> ddply(x, 'LC', sum)
  LC       V1
1  4  86113.4
2  6 215278.0
3  7 456406.5
```

The formatting is perfect, but there is some discrepancies in the values. For example, class 7 should have a value of 456372.4, instead ddply reports a value of 456406.5. A difference of 34.1. All the values are miscalculated.

Can someone explain me why I am having this problem? Am I missing something here? Is my code wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems with your approach:

- You need to tell `ddply` *what* to sum (`Area`). If you don't specify the column, `ddply` sums the values of *all* columns (`ID`, `per`, and `Area`).
- You could aggregate the data with the `summarise` argument.

This code works:

```
x <- read.table(text="  ID LC  per     Area
1  1  7 0.29  62428.3
2  1  7 0.79 170063.3
3  1  4 0.40  86108.0
4  1  7 0.43  92566.1
5  1  6 1.00 215270.0
6  1  7 0.61 131314.7", header = TRUE)


library(plyr)

ddply(x, .(LC), summarise, sum(Area))
```

The result:

```
  LC      ..1
1  4  86108.0
2  6 215270.0
3  7 456372.4
```

Comment: that was fast! thank you so much. This is my first time trying to use plyr.

Comment: @user1896882 You're welcome. If this answer solved your problem, you could accept the answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235.